# How do I change the values which precede and succeed a NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I change the values which precede and succeed an NaN value?

Example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, np.nan, 3, 5 , 6,3,np.nan],"b":[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 
7,2,1,1],"c":[np.nan,4, 8, 9,7,6,5]})
```

Expected Output:

```
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0, np.nan, 0, 5 , 6,0,np.nan],"b":[np.nan, 0, np.nan, 
0,2,1,1],"c":[np.nan,0, 8, 9,7,6,5]})
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be helpful if you shared what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) by chained by `|` for bitwise `OR`values shifted up and down by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and filtered only `non NaN` s by chained by `&` for `bitwise AND`:

```
df = df.mask((df.shift().isna() | df.shift(-1).isna()) & df.notna(), 0)
print (df)
     a    b    c
0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  NaN  8.0
3  5.0  0.0  9.0
4  6.0  2.0  7.0
5  0.0  1.0  6.0
6  NaN  0.0  0.0
```

Another solution with `fill_value` with any values and chained by `|` should be used for not using `notna` mask:

```
df = df.mask(df.shift(fill_value=1).isna() | df.shift(-1, fill_value=1).isna(), 0)
print (df)
     a    b    c
0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  NaN  8.0
3  5.0  0.0  9.0
4  6.0  2.0  7.0
5  0.0  1.0  6.0
6  NaN  1.0  5.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using `shift` and `isna` or `notna`:

```
>>> df[(df.shift().isna() | df.shift(-1).isna()) & df.notna()] = 0
>>> df
     a    b    c
0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  NaN  8.0
3  5.0  0.0  9.0
4  6.0  2.0  7.0
5  0.0  1.0  6.0
6  NaN  0.0  0.0
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `isna()` to get where are `NaN` values then sift `forward` and `backward` to get the preceding and next values and fill them with `0`

```py
df[(df.isna().shift(fill_value=0) + df.isna().shift(-1, fill_value=0)).astype(bool)] = 0



#      a       b    c
# 0  0.0     NaN    NaN
# 1  NaN     0.0    0.0
# 2  0.0     NaN    8.0
# 3  5.0     0.0    9.0
# 4  6.0     2.0    7.0
# 5  0.0     1.0    6.0
# 6  NaN     1.0    5.0
```